$g: R \to R$ is integrable and has compact support. $f(y) =sin^2(y) ln|y|$. Show that $(f ∗ g)(x)$ is well defined for $x \in R$ and of class $C^1$?
$g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R}$ and has a compact support.
$f(y) = \sin^2(y) \ln|y|$
Show that the convolution $(f ∗ g)(x)$ is well defined for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and that it is of class $C^1$ over $\mathbb{R}$.
I know that:
$$h(x) = (f ∗ g)(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin^2(\tau) \ln|\tau| \cdot g(x-\tau) \ d\tau$$
I know that being "well defined" means that it doesn't blow up to $-\infty$ nor $\infty$ anywhere and the class of functions $C^1$ contains functions that have partial derivatives (here, just derivative) and those are continuous.

To show that the convolution $(f ∗ g)(x)$ is well defined for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we can say that limits at $-\infty$ and $\infty$ are not a problem since $g$ has a compact support. We need to check what happens around $0$ with the continuity of $f$.

Show that $\lim_{t\to 0}\sin^2(t)\ln |t| \sim t^2\ln |t|$ exists. Then you can fill in the removable discontinuity and view it as the convolution of an integrable function with a continuous one. The limits at $\pm\infty$ are taken care of by the compactness of $g$'s support. But what is this "theorem" that integrable & compact support means $g'$ exists a.e.? $$g(x) = \begin{cases}\frac 1q& x = \frac pq\in\Bbb Q; \text{gcd}(p,q) = 1; 0\le p \le q\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ has compact support and is integrable, but its derivative does not exist in $[0,1]$.

You should consider transforming the integration so that you can successfully differentiate.

Why do we need to show that $lim_{t \to 0} sin^2(t) ln|t| ~ t^2 ln|t|$ exists? Where did you take $ t^2 ln|t|$ from? I know that $lim_{t \to 0} \frac{sin^2(t)ln|t|}{t^2ln|t|} = 0$, but I don't understand if that's the limit you wanted to check? If I changed the falue of $f(0)$ to $0$ that would cover "filling the removable discontinuity", right? I would like to understand the way I should look at it. @PaulSinclair

You can only claim that setting $f(0) = 0$ removes the discontinuity if you have shown that setting that this value will make $f$ continuous at $0$. I.e., if you have demonstrated that $\lim_{t \to 0} \sin^2 t \ln |t| = 0$. So you have to show that is true first. I'm sorry my notation confused you. I shouldn't have assumed you would be familiar with it (particularly since I was abusing it a bit anyway). I just meant show that the limit of $f(t)$ as $t\to 0$ exists, because that means the function can be made continuous. Saying $\sin^2(t)\ln |t| \sim t^2\ln |t|$ means the two functions (cont)

are asymptotically equal. I.e., that $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin^2t \ln|t|}{t^2\ln|t|} = 1$ (it is not $0$). I shouldn't have included that part. But once you've show that $f$ can be made continuous at $0$, it solves integrability there, and the compact support of $g$ handles the limits at $\pm\infty$, showing well-definedness. And while $g$ might not be differentiable, $f$ is.
